# C# VSTO Excel – get fill color of cell with applied conditional formatting

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

Normally one can get the color of a cell in Excel by using Interior.Color:

```
var r = excelApp.get_Range(“A1”);
Assert.AreEqual(r.Interior.Color, ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Red))
```

However if the cell has a conditional format applied to it (that changes the fill color), the value in `r.Interior.Color` does not change. So if the fill color set by the conditional format is red the value in `r.Interior.Color` is still white.

Or alternatively: Is it possible to see if a conditional format in the r.FormateConditions evaluates to “true”

Comment: I recently wrote a reply on this subject at [Evaluating Data in Conditionally formatted cells by color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068595/evaluating-data-in-conditionally-formatted-cells-by-color-to-return-data-in-a-co/27181378#27181378).

Comment: Thanks for your great reply. I suspected that this won’t work easily.